# Namespaces and Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my application I am using multilevel namespaces. For example I have the following controller:

```
class Admin::Userdesk::AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def show
      ....
  end

  def edit
      ....
  end
end
```

In my routes.rb I have the following:

```
namespace :admin do
    namespace :userdesk do
        resource :dashboards do
        end
        resource :accounts do 
        end
     end
end
```

An issue I am seeing is if I try to link to or navigate to /admin/userdesk/accounts/show/1 or /admin/userdesk/accounts/edit/1 I get the exceptions

`No route matches [GET] "/admin/userdesk/accounts/show/1"`

`No route matches [GET] "/admin/userdesk/accounts/edit1"`

I am not exactly sure where I muxed up my routing. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused by the routes you are testing which is not rails standard. Try this:

Instead of `/admin/userdesk/accounts/show/1`
Try `/admin/userdesk/accounts/1`

And instead of `/admin/userdesk/accounts/edit/1`
Try `/admin/userdesk/accounts/1/edit`

Those should work with your current routes.

Edit:

I also noticed that you use `resource` in your routes.rb. You should probably change that to `resources` (plural).